# How to split Guid correctly?

Tags: c#, split

I have these line of code

```
pic = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, Guid.NewGuid().ToString().IndexOf("-", StringComparison.Ordinal)) + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
```

So normally if I don't use split and index of function I obtain something like this:

```
3de1f910-a8a3-471b-95e8-7f54c299b2b0_650_1200
```

And with split I get only this

```
 3de1f910
```

But how can I do to get to rows like this?

```
 3de1f910-a8a3
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a GUID is standardized and fixed length, you could just give a fixed length for `substring`.

```
pic = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 13) + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
```

Answer (score 1):

From your example it appears you want the string from the second index of `-` where you are getting the first segment of the `Guid`, and for some reason are creating two `Guid`s.

Here are two simple examples (plus spa's example).

**Cool Linq**

```
var pic = string.Join("-", Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Split(new[] { '-' }).Take(2)) + Path.GetExtension(file.Name);
```

**Not so cool `IndexOf`**

```
var g = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
string guidSegment = g.Substring(0, g.IndexOf("-", g.IndexOf("-") + 1));
var pic = guidSegment + Path.GetExtension(file.Name);
```